# Are there any restaurants in the New York area that offer separate men and women seating?

Tags: meal-seudah, mechitza-partition

A few people would like to go out to a restaurant for Thanksgiving dinner. But, they are concerned with meeting there with other family members that the young boys and girls from the family will mingle. So, they asked if there are any restaurants that have either separate seating. Even better, would be a place that has separate dinner hours for men and women.

I'm unaware of any such place in the New York City area, or anywhere, for that matter. Does anyone know of any such place?

Please don't ask why these people want the separate seating. I may think this is unnecessary, but it's not my place to convince them, otherwise.

Please assist with tagging. I'm unsure what's best for this question.

Comment: Why not just split the men and women to different tables?

Comment: @ezra I don't think that would suffice. These people have pretty girls - on par with the beauty of our *imahot*, including Leah :-) At least their parents believe this. So, they really don't want men staring at them. I somewhat understand their predicament.

Comment: OK, whatever the status of the beauty of their girls, there will always be someone who finds them attractive. :) Anyways, we're not here to discuss their parenting strategies. Hey, let them know about [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burqa) they might be interested in purchasing some for their daughters. :P

Comment: This doesn't strike me as a particularly realistic scenario :)

Comment: @Daniel It's not frequent, admittedly. Not that I intend to stereotype, but, I have seen some "strange" behavior among Hassidim and Ba'alei Teshuva. Esp. with the B.T., some go through the motions and can invent their own chumrot and "fears" of things that aren't really there. They are really scared of showing off their girls in public. Ezra's "burka" suggestion may not be that far off, actually, if we could find a Jewish version of it.

Comment: @DanF but they celebrate Thanksgiving?

Comment: @Daniel As I said, it seems that way. Stranger things have happened. Keep in mind, that I think their request isn't specific to Thanksgiving. They prob. would like to just find a place that has separate seating rooms or separate eating hours. Yes, it is an unusual request for somewhat unsual people. I'm uncertain how these girls will get married if they're "hidden".

Comment: This seems to be off topic!

Comment: @ezra My apologies. I got the facts of this wrong. I'm deleting the question.

Comment: @Daniel See ^^^

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I got my facts wrong, as I later discovered. The scenario is irrelevant.

Comment: @DanF You can delete a post without voting to close. Just click delete.

Comment: @mevaqesh - He might not be able to if the question has stayed up for a few days and no one has taken much time to answer it.

Comment: So because the scenario is incorrect, therefore this question has to be closed down? Is it a bad question because you don’t need to know the answer? I also don’t see anything off-topic about it. My vote is too broad, not off-topic.

Comment: @DonielF Normally, I wouldn't request this. However, I don't care to place "waste of time" questions on this site. Yes, there are a number of other ones on M.Y. that I think do the same thing, but I don't feel I have to contribute such questions myself.

Answer (score 2):

Greens restaurant in Williamsburg has a separate seating area for the men and woman.

Comment: Thanks. I should have specified fleishig in my question, I guess. But, at least they may have one option to work with. Otherwise, I sense that they should order from Meal Mart or something, and have separate meals in their home for the men and women. Paper ware and plastics are wonderful inventions, sometimes.

Comment: @DanF - Ya know, why don't they just eat at home if they're so concerned about this? You can have your cake and eat it too.

Comment: @ezra Maybe, if I had the time, energy and patience, I would cook dinner for them and get it to them, somehow. Admittedly, I can't help looking at the girls, myself, so I do understand their concern. I try to avoid going to their home.

Comment: @DanF - Is there some reason why the Baalabusta can't cook for the family? I don't really know what to say. There are plenty of pleasant looking girls out there, and I can't decide whether they are concerned with perverts looking at the girls or they are concerned at causing others to sin. Either way, I think they're going over the top.

Comment: @ezra My guess is that the mom just doesn't want to bother making a Thanksgiving meal, (I can't blame her), and, besides, it seems that her main concern is not having young boys around her girls. Her home most likely can't accomodate the separate seating. She may have to forego this entire idea, I think. Or, just make Thanksgiving during Shabbat kiddush in shul.

Comment: @DanF - Thanksgiving? S'iz nisht a Yiddishe yontif. :)

Comment: My apologies. I got the facts wrong. I'm deleting the question.